# Question about the subtleties of applying Rouche's Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

To find how many zeros of $z^4-2z^3+9z^2+z-1$ are in the disk $|z|<2$, my textbook takes $g(z)=z^4-2z^3+9z^2+z-1$ and $f(z)=9z^2$, and then shows that $|f(z)-g(z)|<|f(z)|$ on $|z|=2$ so the number of zeros of $f$ and $g$ in $|z|<2$ is $2$. I have a few questions about this.

1. How do you know to pick $9z^2$ and is it possible to choose something else, like $z^4$ or $-2z^3+z$?
2. Because $|f(z)-g(z)|=|g(z)-f(z)|$, does that mean I could take $f(z)=z^4-2z^3+9z^2+z-1$ and $g(z)=9z^2$ instead of the other way around (as above)? If I can, I would need to find a lower bound for $|z^4-2z^3+9z^2+z-1|$ using the reverse triangle inequality I believe. So because $|z^4+(-2z^3+9z^2+z-1)|=|z+(z^4-2z^3+9z^2-1)|$ does that mean I could make my lower bound either $||z|^4-2|z|^3-9|z|^2-|z|-1|$ or $||z|-|z|^4-2|z|^3-9|z|^2-1|$?

I would really appreciate a comprehensive response answering both of my questions because my lecturer is terrible and I would really like to understand this because I think it's pretty cool.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, it is possible to pick anything as long as the inequality is satisfied. On how to pick the term consider 
   $$
   g(2w)=16w^4-16w^3+36w^2+2w-1
   $$
   for $|w|=1$ to find that the dominant term is $36w^2$ and that the other terms in total can only reach the absolute value $35$.

You will find that it almost always does not matter if you pick one term or a sum of multiple terms, as the proof of the inequality will pit the dominant term against all the others.

2. Yes, you could. However, it does not seem likely that you can prove the inequality in that setup. You have to take what works.